# Passing text value from one view to another

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have this in my table view controller, and i want to pass the cell's text value to my UITextField on the modal view.

```
- (void)buttonTapped:(id)sender {
    AddName *addName = [[AddName alloc] init];
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell*)[sender superview];
    NSLog(@"text in buttontapped: %@", cell.textLabel.text);
    addName.nameField.text = cell.textLabel.text;
    addName.delegate = self;
    [self presentModalViewController:addName animated:YES];
}
```

The NSLog shows the correct cell text value.

On my modal view's viewDidLoad method i have this... and the text value never gets set...

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"text: %@",nameField.text);
    nameField.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeWords;
    nameField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeDefault;
    [nameField becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

What's going on?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as though you're assuming that the modal view controller has already loaded its view, since I'm assuming `nameField` is a subview. But clearly at the point that your code is trying to set its `text` property, the text field and its parent view haven't been loaded yet, so you're sending a `-setText:` message to `nil`.

Instead, add a property to your modal view controller of type `NSString *`, and set that in your `buttonTapped` implementation. Then, in the modal view controller's `-viewWillAppear` method, you can take the value from the property and put it into the text field.